Vega Chart Not Plotting as Expected
I am trying to create a vega chart and can not seem to get the marks to show up where expected. The y axis seems to update to a reasonable scale based on what the values are but the data points do not seem to be at the appropiate height.  I am sure this is a simple mistake but I can not figure it out.
Here is the related gist for my issue: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/49a8f907acc115656d70fc5bfacc8f65/spec.json
